# chromedriver.exe not closing in selenium c#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

Tests are run only after manually entering the command into the console: C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe /im chromedriver.exe /f

When restarting tests, an error occurs:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State

Error MSB3061 Unable to delete file "C:\Users\User\SolutionName\ProjectName\bin\Debug\net6.0\chromedriver.exe".

Access to the path 'C:\Users\User\SolutionName\ProjectName\bin\Debug\net6.0\chromedriver.exe' is denied.

Project: ProjectName

File: C:\Users\User\SolutionName\ProjectName\bin\Debug\net6.0\chromedriver.exe\107.0.5304.6200\build\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.targets 94

Has anyone come across? Tell me what to do.

I removed NuGet Selenium.chromedriver from the tests that had this error and the tests started to run, but there are many processes in the task manager named Chromedriver.exe

Answer (score 0):

At the end of each your Selenium test you have to close the session by `driver.quit()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem every time my browser got updated which cause session failure. 
You can surround the driver creation with this code:

```
try
{
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    // Some code
    driver.Quit();
}
catch
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver");
    foreach (Process process in processes)
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
}
```

This way on **success** you will execute `driver.Quit` 
And on **failure** you will execute `process.kill` on each `chromedriver` process.